# How to make this Google Sheet formula, into an array formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

We have a Google Sheet table that's the target for a Google Form. It has multiple choice responses in column M that are strings containing numbers.

Example: 3. The mentor team clearly assigned..., 4. The mentor team knew the..., 5. The mentor team knew the choice..., 7. The mentor team came early on..., 8. The children were...

We need an array formula to:

- extract the numbers
- sum them
- for each non-empty row in column M

We have the below working formula, but we need it to be an array formula because the spreadsheet is ever growing with new entries from the form.

`=SUM(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(M2,"[^\d\.]+"," ")," ")))`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
=BYROW(FILTER(M2:M,M2:M<>""),LAMBDA(sx, 
         SUM(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(sx,"[^\d\.]+"," ")," ")))))
```

This will skip any empty rows but will "mess" with the order of the answers.

To keep `0`s for empty rows use this formula

```
=BYROW(M2:M,LAMBDA(sx, 
   SUM(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(sx,"[^\d\.]+"," ")," ")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Alternate Solution

You can also achieve this by utilizing the `MAP` and `REDUCE` functions available in Google Sheets, as demonstrated in the following example:

`=MAP(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(M2:M, NOT(ISBLANK(M2:M))), "[^\d\.]+", ".")), LAMBDA(cell, REDUCE(0,SPLIT(cell,"."),LAMBDA(accumulator, current_value, accumulator+current_value))))`

*This sample formula follows the following flow:*

1. Get all of the numbers in each of the cells in Column M.
2. Process each gathered number using the `MAP` function, cell by cell.
3. Each cell will be passed into the `SPLIT` function, to separate the numbers.
4. Once all the numbers have been separated, they will be passed into the `REDUCE` function to calculate their sum.
5. Return the total per cell of each value.

### Demo

[image]

### References:

- [Google Sheet MAP Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985)
- [Google Sheet Reduce Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597)

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(BYROW(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(M2:M,"[^\d\.]+"," ")," ")),LAMBDA(row,SUM(row))))
```

Or:

```
=MAP(M2:M,LAMBDA(z,SUM(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(z,"[^\d\.]+"," ")," ")))))
```

Comment: All were awesome solutions. We used the 1st one here with the Arrayformula since there were other little tweaks we needed to make and we were more familiar with this format. Many, many thanks to all contributors, we were desperately stuck.